# How to install GNU make on FreeBSD 10?

Tags: freebsd

I have this error

```
configure: error: GNU make is required!
```

and I can't change into `/usr/ports/devel/gmake/`

```
$ cd /usr/ports/devel/gmake/
cd: /usr/ports/devel/gmake/: No such file or directory
```

How can I install GNU make on FreeBSD 10?

Answer (score 9):

`pkg install gmake`

also, you have to install the ports tree if you want to be able to install ports from source.

Comment: @soft-developer You can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, rather than just deleting the question

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the ports tree installed

run `portsnap fetch extract`
This will download and install the ports tree.

In the future, you can run: `portsnap fetch update`
This will update the ports tree and offer you newer versions of gmake

You can also install the pre-compiled gmake from the package system:
`pkg install devel/gmake`